# When do we use "zu" instead of "in" for locations

Tags: preposition

I know prepositions of place zu and in but according to some dictionaries like duden and dwds it says things I don't understand like duden says "designates the place, the position of being, the way something is played out and DWDS says something in a certain place, in a certain position and I don't understand that please somebody explain simply

Comment: Can you give examples of sentences where you wonder whether the oder shouldn't be used? Can you link the quotes from duden and dwds to their sources so that we can actually follow your train of through?

Comment: there are some examples outside Duden and DWDS the one in duden it says designates the place, the position, the way something is played out and it gives the example "man erreicht diesen Ort zu Wasser und zu Lande" I don't understand it also there are some examples like "ins bett gehen" and "zu bett gehen" also "ins fitnessstudio gehen" and "Zum fitnessstudio gehen" what is the difference? Also the example from duden can't be used with "in" but I don't understand how that means designates the position, place, the way something is played out

Comment: In English you have in, to and into. I walk in / to / into  the house. You can edit your actual question with these examples

Answer (score 0):

Generally, prepositions don't translate 1:1 - and individual prepositions are used for different purposes so that translations will vary. Here it is mostly places and directions. Maybe we start also with an example here:

> Ich gehe im Haus. (in + Dativ)

This describes a place of the action: I walk in the house (in circles or similar).

> Ich gehe ins Haus (in + Akkusativ)
> Ich gehe ins Fitnessstudio
> Ich gehe ins Bett

This describes a direction with crossing the boundary (in)to the object: I walk into the house / I go into the house. With the bed it's figuratively: you (in)to bed.

> Ich gehe zum Haus (zu + Dativ)
> Ich gehe zum Fitnessstudio
> Ich gehe zum Bett

This describes a direction towards the object, but not necessarily entering it: I walk to the house / I go to the house.

With "Bett" there is the somewhat fixed expression "zu Bett gehen" which is nearly synonymous to "ins Bett gehen" (to go to bed).

As to the other examples in your comment, that's different:

> zu Lande und zu Wasser

This describes a mode (of transport) where you are on top of the thing (thus it's not a direction or place: "by land or by sea". Similar: zu Fuß, zu Pferde, but it does not work with "Auto", "Flugzeug" or "Zug": "mit dem Auto / Flugzeug / Zug" or "im Auto / ...".

Comment: Yes I understand but if I translate "I travel by land" without "by water" it translates into "Ich reise auf dem Landweg" because "auf" means on I think literally it means "I travel on land" is that right?

Comment: travel by land = auf dem Landweg reisen / zu Land(e) reisen. The latter is less common and a bit old fashioned but still correct German

Comment: There are also examples where "zu" could be replaced with "in", e.g. "*Zu* Regensburg auf der Kirchturmspitz" (a folk song title) or "Humboldt-Universität *zu* Berlin". This old-fashioned use of "zu" is still present in some dialects, e.g. "z Minga" = "zu München" = "in München".

Comment: Im Frühtau zu Berge... :) https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5KDp4DVUgtE